# Does URLConnection's getInputStream() return the same InputStream every time?

Tags: java, android, inputstream, urlconnection

It is very common to get an InputStream from URLConnection like so:

```
InputStream stream =  connection.getInputStream();
```

where connection is a `URLConnection`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream()

I have a situation where I would like to reuse a stream. I have access to the connection object and my question now is does a single instance of a URLConnection return the 'same' InputStream every time ? That is if I call connection.getInputStream() again (but for the same connection object) will I be getting a new stream ?

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer to this kind of question ("Does X do Y?") is: Does the documentation *say* X does Y? If so, yes (or it's broken); if not, you have no guarantee so and must assume not.

So let's look at [`URLConnection#getInputStream`'s documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream--):

> Returns an input stream that reads from this open connection. A SocketTimeoutException can be thrown when reading from the returned input stream if the read timeout expires before data is available for read.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> an input stream that reads from this open connection.

So you can't *rely* on it doing so, because it doesn't promise to. (I also looked elsewhere in the JavaDoc for `URLConnection`.)

(My tests outside Android suggest that `HttpURLConnection` does at least sometimes, though.)

Answer (score 1):

`URLConnection` is an interface and it all depends on the implementors if the `getInputStream` returns a new stream or not.

The best way to verify this is...

```
URLConnection con = new URL(MY_URL_STRING).openConnection() ;
InputStream in1 = con.getInputStream(); 
InputStream in2 = con.getInputStream();
boolean streamEquals = in1.equals(in2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. It wouldn't make any difference whether it did or it didn't. Consider a method that always returns `new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())`. (I don't claim it *is* implemented like that: we are just considering.) There is nothing practical you can do with the stream short of comparing it with `==` that would tell you whether it was a new stream each time like that or always the same stream. What you read out of it is not affected.